# Can I be held responsible for objects abandoned by other tenants?

Tags: residential-lease, netherlands

I live in the Netherlands (Amsterdam to be specific), in an apartment building with two communal spaces (a bike cellar and a currently unused room).

In the bike cellar there are many broken and abandoned old bikes, and because of this there isn't enough space anymore. In the unused room, many tenants dumped broken furniture. Tenants only live in the building for a few years, so the original owners may very well have moved out.

Today all tenants (I assume) received an email from the real estate company managing (but not owning) the building:

> Dear Tenants,
>
> (...)
>
> We therefore send you this email to inform you that the [unused room] needs to be cleaned out by you, and also that all old/broken bicycles need to be removed [from the bike cellar, presumably].
>
> (...)
>
> If this is not arranged by the tenants within 3 weeks, we will arrange a company to throw everything away and the costs for this will be charged to all tenants in the building.

I object to this; I didn't abandon any bikes or furniture in these spaces (or anywhere else for that matter), so obviously I don't want to clear out the stuff other tenants left and neither do I want to pay for it.

As far as I can tell, the only law or clause in my lease that could make me responsible for removing abandoned objects is the law requiring tenants to carry out "kleine herstellingen" (small restorations). It's also specified in my lease (but I don't see why, as it is a law already). These "kleine herstellingen" entail carrying out all cleaning and maintenance that is easy and cheap (really, these are the criteria the government gives) of the rented space, and also of shared spaces. However, all tenants pay an extra fee on top of our rent for a cleaning service. It seems to me, we thereby fulfil our requirement to keep communal spaces clean. On the website the Dutch government about these "small restorations", it is specifically mentioned that this is a common arrangement.

## TL;DR

There are some points on which I have doubts:

1. It seems to me that, although abandoning furniture in communal spaces is prohibited by my lease (and rightly so), the regulations concerning "kleine herstellingen", which entail "cleaning and maintenance", do not cover throwing out abandoned furniture. Is this correct?
2. If the requirement to carry out "kleine herstellingen" does cover this, to what extent is this responsibility shared between tenants, i.e. am I obligated to remove the objects dumped by other tenants?
3. Is there another law or provision which obligates me to remove objects abandoned by other tenants?

I would also very much appreciate advice on how to proceed. I imagine I should reply to the  email from the company managing the property threatening to charge all tenants if the abandoned objects aren't removed, but I am not sure what exactly to write.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but (1) was the junk already there when you moved in?  (2) can you prove that none of it was left by you or your guests?

Comment: (1) at least a large portion of the bicycles, was there already. The abandoned furniture in the unused room is more recent, because it was emptied by the cleaning staff a few times over the past few years. I’m not sure why the managing company is now taking an interest, although I wholeheartedly agree that’s not the job of the cleaning staff. (2) no but that reeks of “guilty until proven innocent”. At least with the “kleine herstellingen” law, burden of proof is with the landlord. I can’t even imagine how one would go about proving this. @NateEldredge